# OWL-Carousel - width under 768px - Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, typo3, owl-carousel

I have a big problem with OWL-Carousel and my Website.
I kicked all CSS and JS files, now I load only jQuery JS, Bootstrap CSS, OWL CSS and JS.
I resize the Window over 768px, the Slider works fine! 767px the Template and the OWL go in the 100% Bootstrap width. And now the OWL calculated the Site/Container- width wrong! the Container have xx.xxx px width :/

I use the OWL default Example:
http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/demos/basic.html

here the Link: https://www.indoor-golf.org/anlagen/hotel-riml-hochgurgl/?no_cache=1
(Indoor-Golf Partner)

thanks for helping! Sebastian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error :(

```
#outer-wrapper .page-wrap {
  background-color: #f4f4f2;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}
```

the `display:table`

Comment: thanks, but i must wait 24 hours from the system :) thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing the bootstrap classes with owl carousel by using both .carousel and .owl-carousel in one div. This probably breaks things by trying to initiate two different carousel javascripts on the same code. Try removing the .carousel class and write all your CSS for the slider with owl-carousel class only.

Comment: hi @JozefSpisiak i use only the classes from OWL: .owl-carousel
And in the JS it the same.
no class i found in the source.

Comment: Sorry, it was from startpage, where you are mixing the classes, not on the hotel page. Why is the hotel page missing images?

Comment: i clear all css/jss to minimize error :) jep the example is on the "Detail-Page" i dont find the "error" :/